# Wrap ButtonElement to Button

Tags: java, gwt

I'm trying to wrap a ButtonElement into a Button:

```
@UiField ButtonElement myButton;

Button theButton = Button.wrap(myButton);
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
@UiField myButton, template field and owner field types don't match: com.google.gwt.dom.client.ButtonElement is not assignable to com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Button
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that while you have a `ButtonElement` in your java code, the uibinder tag with the name "myButton" is actually a `Button` widget, not a `ButtonElement` elt.

Change the uibinder to actually use a `<button>`, or change the `@UiField` to be a Button (and drop the `wrap(...)` call).